# Importar imagens em destaque, sem ter que fazer o download delas. - WORDPRESS

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Estou trabalhando em um site que tem noticias desde 2001.

Gostaria de exportar apenas os seus ( posts + imagens em destaque) de 2015 para trás, mas não preciso fazer download das imagens então imagino que tudo seja por banco de dados.

O exportador padrão do Wordpress não funciona, e os plugins que fazem esse serviço fazem o download da imagem(não preciso pois as imagens estão em um blob).

Como faço para fazer a coleta desses dados ? Sei que o conteúdo que preciso está em wp_posts wp_post_metas

Comment: Kaue se vc não conseguir a resposta aqui existem tb uma plataforma da StackExchange apena para Wordpress https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Muito Obrigado !

Answer (score 0):

Se você tem acesso SSH ao servidor, pode usar a [WP CLI](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/db/export/) para exportar somente o que quiser do banco:

```
$ wp db export --tables=wp_posts,wp_postmeta posts.sql
```

Esse comando exporta somente as tabelas `wp_posts` e `wp_postmeta` para um arquivo `posts.sql` que você pode importar no novo banco.